# mysql trigger after insert send data to another mysql host

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is possible clone a mysql table to remote server using trigger after insert? or exist better sollution? thank you in advice

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. What you need to look into is creating a Federates storage engine. This will allow you to create a "proxy" table in your database server, which points to a real table on another server. This setting is disabled by default so you will need to change that.

Your trigger would would act as follows:

On some table T INSERT into your FEDERATED table FT. This will then connect to the remote server, authenticate and perform the operation. I would be quite weary of lag and latency if you will be making several actions which will execute use this trigger.